# Omniauth: How to set authentication provider details at runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, middleware, omniauth

I have a rails app that is accessible from 2 domains. Facebook requires me to register a facebook app for each of these domains and gives me credentials for each. With Omniauth I can only specify one set of credentials that is set on application startup. However, I would need to supply FB with different credentials depending on the host of the request.

There are 2 problems here:

1. How can I change the Omniauth credentials for facebook at runtime?
2. How can I intercept the call to facebook, check the domain and set the credentials accordingly? A before filter will not work, as Omniauth uses Rack Middleware.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: Okay, I did find instructions to do this here: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Dynamic-Providers However, they don't work for me. Omniauth goes straight to the provider, even if I setup the route to intercept the 'provider/auth' call...  I'm using Rails 2.3.5 with Omniauth 0.1.6

Comment: Okay, I updated the gem to version 0.2.0.beta4 and the route works now but even though I set the environment vars to the correct credentials I get an authentication failure. The authorization url to facebook looks exactly the same like when setting up the credentials manually in the config. By the way, the vars are now called (client_id and client_secret not consumer_key and consumer_secret as it says in the wiki).

Comment: I solved this myself now. The problem was that the fb strategy calls back to fb a second time to get an access token. In that second call the wrong credentials were used (the ones set in the initializer). So I had to patch the OAuth2 strategy so that it calls through to the rails app again, to set the runtime credentials for that second call. In the call back, which normally only handles the response form Omniauth, I set the credentials and return a 404 unless request.env["omniauth.auth"] is present. That works fine but has some side effects for apps without dynamic providers.

Comment: The problem is now, tht even if an application doesn't want to set the credentials at runtime, it has to add a condition to the callback like if request.env["omniauth.auth"] to avoid the callback code beeing executed when it is called the first time. The solution is probbaly to add a parameter to the Omniauth builder like :dynamic_provider and only call through to the app if it is set.

Comment: I see you are using Rails 2.3.5 and Omniauth 0.1.6. I can't get them to work together, as rails 2.3.5 requies Rack 1.0.1 and Omniauth requires Rack 1.1 Any help very much appreciated. Paul

Comment: Hi Paul, I use Rack 1.2.1 and removed the dependency to Rack 1.0.1 from Rails (I have vendored it). I also patched Rack in lib/rack/utils.rb: I changed the definition of ESCAPE_HTML_PATTERN to ESCAPE_HTML_PATTERN = Regexp.union(*ESCAPE_HTML.keys). Let me know if this does the trick for you.

Comment: @Nico - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> I solved this myself now. The problem was that the fb strategy calls
> back to fb a second time to get an access token. In that second call
> the wrong credentials were used (the ones set in the initializer). So
> I had to patch the OAuth2 strategy so that it calls through to the
> rails app again, to set the runtime credentials for that second call.
> In the call back, which normally only handles the response form
> Omniauth, I set the credentials and return a 404 unless
> request.env["omniauth.auth"] is present. That works fine but has some
> side effects for apps without dynamic providers.
>
> The problem is now, that even if an application doesn't want to set the credentials at runtime, it has to add a condition to the callback like if request.env["omniauth.auth"] to avoid the callback code being executed when it is called the first time. The solution is probably to add a parameter to the Omniauth builder like :dynamic_provider and only call through to the app if it is set.

~ answer per [Nico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361418/nico)

Answer (score 1):

This question is fairly old but still relevant. Nowdays it is also possible to set provider details dynamically during OmniAuth's Setup Phase.

For example:

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use do
  provider :example, 
    setup: ->(env) do
      env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:foo] = env['rack.session']['foo']
      env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_options][:site] = Something.dynamic('param')
  end
end
```

Source: https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Dynamic-Providers